# how can i add contact form 7 in metaslider in wordpress, I want to display different form when image is slide

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using two wordpress plugin

1- Metaslider

2- Contact form7

I want to display CF7 in metaslider, there is two different images and in each images i want to display CF7.

Is it possible or not.

**Metaslider is must require**

Here is some other link but this link through i cant find actual output.

[Link-1](https://siteorigin.com/thread/embed-contact-form-shortcode-into-slider/)

[Link-2](https://docs.presscustomizr.com/article/201-creating-a-contact-page-withcontact-form-7-and-the-customizr-theme)

[Link-3](https://www.themepunch.com/faq/add-contact-form-7/)

Comment: While considering CF7 shortcode result as an HTML output. Metaslider PRO only has the support for HTML slides.

Comment: Great, Thank you for suggestion, Let me talk to team metaslider.